# Establishing an inequality related to a convex order.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables such that $X\leq_{cx}Y$, that is $Y$ bigger than $X$ in the convex order (which means $E[\phi(X)]\leq E[\phi(Y)]$ for all convex function $\phi$).Then is it possible to establish $min\{x|F_{X}(x)= 1\} \leq min\{x|F_{Y}(x)=1\}$?

Comment: Of course. Suppose otherwise, that is $M_X>M_Y$. Then setting $\phi(x)=\max(0,x-M_Y)$ leads to contradiction.

Comment: So you mean $E[\phi(Y)]=0$ and $E[\phi(X)]>0$?

Comment: But how do we get the contradiction?

Comment: Suppose $M_Y<\infty$. Then $0=E(\phi(Y))\ge E(\phi(X))$. It follows that $M_X\le M_Y$.

Comment: I am sorry, but why $0=E(ϕ(Y))≥E(ϕ(X))$ implies $M_X≤M_Y$? .